# 1 Cor 15:25 - Does Jesus stop reigning? What's the actual function and meaning of "until" in the context of this verse?

Tags: christology, eschatology, kingdom, god, biblical-theology

> 23 But each in his own order: Christ the firstfruits, then at his coming those who belong to Christ. 24 *Then comes the end, when he delivers the kingdom to God the Father* after destroying every rule and every authority and power. **25 For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet.** 26 The last enemy to be destroyed is death. 27 For “God has put all things in subjection under his feet.” But when it says, “all things are put in subjection,” it is plain that he is excepted who put all things in subjection under him. 28 When all things are subjected to him, then the Son himself will also be subjected to him who put all things in subjection under him, that God may be all in all.
> **-1 Corinthians 15:23-28**

In English, the straightforward implication of this verse is that Jesus's reign is coming to an end where the authority he previously was granted is handed over to God. Just doesn't seem right that the Messiah having been promised an everlasting kingdom (2 Sam 7:12-14) would at some point not rule the kingdom promised.

> **Luke 1:30-33** (ESV)
> And the angel said to her, "Do not be afraid, Mary, for you have found favor with God. And behold, you will conceive in your womb and bear a son, and you shall call his name Jesus. He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. And the Lord God will give to him the throne of his father David, and he will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and of **his kingdom there will be no end**."

How is "until" meant to communicate in the context of this passage? How does it work if we otherwise understand Jesus's rule to persist even after he delivers the kingdom to God?

Comment: The traditional beliefs about the law has also been that it was meant to be eternal, thus, a big hurdle for the traditional jews to believe in Jesus. The term eternal and many other such terms are often metaphorical. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81256/is-the-law-eternal

Comment: In order to provide a meaningful answer to this question, one needs to decide if they want to know what the author of Luke said or, what the author of 1 Corinthians 15 said. You can slather Luke and Paul and stick them together, but, like magnets of the same polarity, they will still be at cross purposes. Different authors, working with different version of the LXX, routinely come up with conflicting assertions.

Answer (score 3):

> And the seventh angel sounded; and there were great voices in heaven, saying, The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of our Lord, and of his Christ; **and he shall reign for ever and ever**.  [Revelation 11:15 KJV]

> And there shall be no night there; and they need no candle, neither light of the sun; for the Lord God giveth them light: **and they shall reign for ever and ever.** [Revelation 22:5 KJV]

After the judgment of the beast, the false prophet, Diabolos himself and all his demons and all who worship the beast and are subject to diabolic and demonic rule and influence - all being cast into the lake of fire - then shall there be new heavens and new earth.

Then is the everlasting kingdom established.

Hitherto, Christ ruled over the spirits of his own, within the body of the church. But at the end of time, he shall be granted to rule all nations with a rod of iron.

Given the nations, he does not rule over them, naturally and carnally - rather he exerts judgment and smashes them to pieces as a man shatters clay pottery with an iron rod.

Then, then, shall there be new heavens and new earth and the reign of Christ over that *cleansed creation* shall be established.

And it shall never cease.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be no doubt that the spiritual kingdom of Jesus is eternal as repeatedly asserted in the Bible:

- Luke 1:32, 33 - He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. The Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David, and He will reign over the house of Jacob forever. **His kingdom will never end**!”
- Rev 11:15 - Then the seventh angel sounded his trumpet, and loud voices called out in heaven: “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ, and **He will reign forever and ever**.”
- Rev 22:5 - There will be no more night in the city, and they will have no need for the light of a lamp or of the sun. For the Lord God will shine on them, and **they will reign forever and ever**.
- Heb 1:8 - But about the Son He says: “Your throne, O God, **endures forever** and ever, and justice is the scepter of Your kingdom.
- 2 Peter 1:11 - For in this way the entrance into **the eternal kingdom of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ** will be richly supplied to you.
- Isa 9:7 - Of the increase of His [Messiah's] government and peace **there will be no end**. He will reign on the throne of David and over his kingdom, to establish and sustain it with justice and righteousness from that time and **forevermore**. The zeal of the LORD of Hosts will accomplish this.

So, what are we to make of Jesus reigning "until" (Gr: ἄχρι achri) "all the enemies are under His feet"?  This is less complicated than it appears - it simply means that Jesus will continue to reign, uninterrupted, until all enemies are conquered and well beyond (forever).  That is, the existence of Jesus' enemies will be no impediment to Jesus reign.

Answer (score 0):

Scripture is straightforward in Jesus rule over the house of Jacob for the coming eons.  If you look at the interlinear on Bible Hub, it says for the ages.

There are five ages or eons that are referred to in scripture, but so often it's hard to see because many translators use the word eternal which is not correct because ages, eons,  and olam always deal with periods of time.

> Definition of  eternal;
> something that's always been and always will be.

Ages or eons have a definite beginning and end.  Jesus rule is for the next two eons where everything will eventually be subjected to Christ.

This word aion is used in Luke 1:33 with regard to how long His reign will be.

> ◄ 165. aión ►
> Strong's Concordance
> aión: a space of time, an age

> Definition: a space of time, an age
> Usage: an age, a cycle (of time), especially of the present age as contrasted with the future age, and of one of a series of ages

The word olam in 2 Samuel 12-14 also means for a long time.

> He doth build a house for My Name, and I have established the throne of his kingdom unto the age. 2 Samuel 7:13

> ◄ 5769. olam ►
> Strong's Concordance
> olam: long duration, antiquity, futurity

> He shall be great, and shall be called the Son of the Most High, and the Lord God shall be giving Him the throne of David, His father, and He shall be reigning over the house of Jacob, for the eons, and of His kingdom there shall be no consummation.  Luke 1:32-33

> The reign of Christ is for the eons, a long but limited period.  He then gives up the kingdom to God, the Father , so that the kingdom itself is endless.
> (1 Co. 15:24). The negative is the only means used in the scripture to denote endlessness.  Concordant commentary.

Conclusion;  I will let scripture speak for itself.

> 24then — the end, when he may deliver up the reign to God, even the Father, when he may have made useless all rule, and all authority and power — 25for it behoveth him to reign till he may have put all the enemies under his feet — 26the last enemy is done away — death; 27for all things He did put under his feet, and, when one may say that all things have been subjected, [it is] evident that He is excepted who did subject the all things to him, 28and when the all things may be subjected to him, then the Son also himself shall be subject to Him, who did subject to him the all things, that God may be the all in all. YLT
> 1 Corinthians 15:24:28

Answer (score -1):

Jesus has always been with God from the very beginning (John 1:1-2). It is Jesus who created whatever is created (John 1:3). Even God the Father declares the same truth regarding Jesus, “You, Lord, at the beginning founded the earth, and the heavens are works of Your hands. They will vanish away, but You will continue……… But You are the same, and Your years shall not fail” (Hebrews 1:10-12).

When the Logos “became flesh and tabernacled among us” (John 1:14), this was the time when the Word was away from God the Father! That is why Jesus said, “I came out from the Father and have come into the world; I leave the world again and go to the Father” (John 16:28).

Currently Jesus is placed at the right hand of God the Father (Romans 8:34).

During the Millennium, when Jesus will rule over the Earth for a thousand years, He will be away from God the Father.

Then, after the thousand years, at the very End, God the Father comes down for the first time to the Earth to be with Jesus and all.

“And I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth passed away……….. Behold, the tabernacle of God with men! And He will tabernacle with them, and they will be His people, and **God Himself will be with them as their God**” (Revelation 21:1, 3).

This is what is meant by the Son delivering the kingdom to God the Father.

Does it mean that Jesus will stop reigning as King?

Not at all!

First of all, Jesus has NEVER reigned without being in subjection to His Father. He declared, “My Father is greater than I” (John 14:28). Yes, God the Father is greater than the Word Jesus *in authority*.

The truth is, God the Father and Jesus, under Him, will rule **together**!

“but the **throne** of God **and** of the Lamb shall be in it” (Revelation 22:3).
“coming forth out of the **throne** of God **and** of the Lamb” (Revelation 22:1).

Note:- A throne is a symbol of power and reign. So here, we see both God the Father and Jesus sitting on the same throne and ruling.

So, Jesus’ reign is indeed everlasting. He will never stop reigning!

Comment: Moderators, is there a way I can know why I am given a negative mark? Factual error, bad language, a (theological) dislike of the answer etc?